# Cordova How can I stop loading certain links in InappBrowser?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I want to open a website at InappBrowser, but the user should remain on this site. If the user clicks a link or is redirected to another site, the link will not be loaded.

```
var url="https://facebook.com"
var site=cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url,"_blank","location=yes")

site.addEventListener("loadstart",function(evt){
    if(evt.url.indexOf("youtube.com") > 1){
        site.stopLoad() //this is the code supposed to stop the loading
    } else {
        //yes can load the link
    }
})
```